# How to impliment an implement which has an interface property?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm wanting a class to have a property that is another class, but i want both the outside and inside classes to implement an interface, the outside interface having a property for the one on the inside.

Here's the code I've tried.

```
interface IMainBody
{
    ISubProperty subProperty { get; set; }
}
interface ISubProperty
{
    string somethingHere { get; set; }
}
class MainBody : IMainBody // Error CS0738  'MainBody' does not implement interface member 'IMainBody.subProperty'. 'MainBody.subProperty' cannot implement 'IMainBody.subProperty' because it does not have the matching return type of 'ISubProperty'.
{
    public SubProperty subProperty { get; set; }
}
class SubProperty : ISubProperty
{
    public string somethingHere { get; set; }
}
```

I know I could use a generic interface like this

```
interface IMainBody<T>
    where T : ISubProperty
{
    T subProperty { get; set; }
}
interface ISubProperty
{
    string somethingHere { get; set; }
}
```

But I would prefer not to do this because it means the code will get very messy once there is more than one property like this.

Anyone know of any other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainBody : IMainBody 
{
    public SubProperty subProperty { get; set; }
    ISubProperty IMainBody.subProperty { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

Comment: I know this works, but I want to enforce the members of the ISubProperty interface, but also be able to have others.

Comment: not following your comment re enforce. the two solutions above do the job. I would not overthink it